# Why is graphql-tag needed to use Apollo with Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

I'm trying to understand why most tutorials on Nuxt and Apollo also suggest installing the [graphql-tag package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tag).

The @nuxt/apollo module docs [say](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/apollo#3--loading-gql-or-graphql-files-optional) this is optional, if you want to load separated `.gql` files (as opposed to... writing your queries inline in your components?) And the [official Nuxt/Apollo demo](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/vue-apollo) uses separated `.gql` files despite *not* having graphql-tag installed.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365316/why-do-you-need-graphql-tag-with-apollo), but it doesn't really seem to answer my question. It just talks about query parsing.

Can anyone tell me precisely what graphql-tag does and whether (and how, in theory) you'd use Apollo with Nuxt *without* it installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a graphQL expert but I still achieved to work with it the few last months. At the end, I found out that `graphql-tag` is only useful when using inline queries directly into your `.vue` components.

Like in this [documentation section](https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/apollo/#queries)

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ hello }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export default {
  apollo: {
    // Simple query that will update the 'hello' vue property
    hello: gql`query {
      hello
    }`,
  },
}
</script>
```

Meanwhile, since it's not very flexible, I've ended up importing and using it in Vuex like this

```js
import myGqlQuery from '~/apollo/queries/test.gql'

const actions = {
  async myFancyVuexAction({ commit, dispatch }) {
    try {
      const { errors, data } = await this.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({ query: myGqlQuery })
    } else {
      // error
    }
  }
}
```

With the `.gql` imported file being written like this

```
query{
  Entity {
    things
  }
}
```

For this kind of configuration, you **don't** need `graphql-tag`. Also, some people have some flexible configuration inside of their graphql files, they are using vanilla `.js` files and a mix of their actual GQL query + `graphql-tag` (needed if it's not a `.gql` file).

---

It is also useful if using TypeScript, here is an example: https://github.com/DNature/chef-assignment/blob/master/apollo/queries/index.ts

So yeah, those are my 2cts. Not a pro, but things that I understood from my few months fiddling with GraphQL.